# Saving state of application accross views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I have simple app and one view that is about to change via navigation bar.
Default `angular's` behaviour is to call controller code every time I am navigating. This arise problem of saving state when changing views (i.e calendar state, checkboxes etc.)

I search for most common well known solution, that is why I am asking below questions:

1. Should I encapsulate state data in service and load every time controller is called? And this is fine?
2. Should I prevent situation of calling controller every time I am switching to different menu view?
3. Does `angular-route` handle for me preventing of calling controller every time view changed.
4. Does `ui-router` handle same as pt. 3?

Comment: That's a lot of questions, perhaps nix 3 and 4 and focus on 1?  #2 could be its own question as well.

Comment: In most cases if you follow RESTful conventions, all of your state will be encapsulated in the route/URL, and query parameters.

Comment: @NicholasSmith you mean if I have i.e calendar and few checkboxes all changes on calendar and checkboxes should be reflected in url?

Comment: I'm not sure what your use case is, but wouldn't those checkbox / calendar entries be saved in the database and re-populated to the page when you navigate / refresh?  Or do you have an app where the user needs to go through several screens modifying data before they actually commit and save their changes?